# CSS perspective not working

Tags: html, css, transform

I'm trying to create a cube with CSS. I actually think it's already there but I can't see it.
Feel free to [edit the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ca5YX/).

I don't understand why the perspective is not working.
Is this best practice?

Is it possible to rotate the cube as a whole??

Source: [24ways](http://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms).

HTML:

```
<section class="container">
      <div id="cube">
        <figure class="front">1</figure>
        <figure class="back">2</figure>
        <figure class="right">3</figure>
        <figure class="left">4</figure>
        <figure class="top">5</figure>
        <figure class="bottom">6</figure>
      </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  margin: 200px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
 }

 #cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 }

#cube figure {
  width: 198px;
  height: 198px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#cube .front { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px); }
#cube .back { -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(100px); }
#cube .right { -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px); }
#cube .left { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }
#cube .top { -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px); }
#cube .bottom { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem could be that the hardware acceleration was not supported on your PC and it was on your mac... css3d transformations such as `rotateX` and `rotateY` require hardware accelerations.

in chrome go to your address bar and enter

> chrome://gpu

you will see

> 3D CSS: Unavailable. Hardware acceleration disabled.

if this is the case then 3d cube is not visible.

Answer (score -1):

I used to work with a lot of 3D Transforms a while ago but recently noticed that CSS3 perspective does not have any effect on my web browsers including Chrome.
Tried the following and it helped in Google Chrome:

1. Navigate to "chrome://flags"
2. Find an item labeled "Override software rendering list" and disable it
3. Relaunch your browser

I know its a bit late but just in case it might help you...